# why In I2C the min fall time for Fast and Fast Plus mode is 20ns*(VDD/5.5)?

Tags: i2c

How have they derived 20ns(VDD/5.5)?[image]

Comment: They haven't derived it - at 5.5 volts it'll be 20 ns and if the actual supply is lower, that time will reduce.

Comment: How will it be 20ns at 5.5?

Comment: Simple math: 20 ns x 5.5/5.5 = 20 ns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not derived from anywhere. When the 400 kHz Fast Mode was defined, it was specified that the output drivers must have slew rate limiting to limit signal bandwidth, which prevents electromagnetic interference and signal reflections.

Comment: Yes this produce 1st null of EMI at 50MHz at 5.5V and followon harmonics reduced.

Comment: Tony can you elaborate further.
Can you please give the mathematical expression of 1st null that is seen at 50MHz at 5.5